# Are loops not allowed when gluing together simplices in a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm taking a graduate geometric topology class and our professor made a quick remark that we're not allowed to make stuff like these by gluing together simplexes in a simplicial complex. I didn't get time to ask him to clarify, but does it mean that loops are not allowed when gluing together simplices to form a simplicial complex? Any ideas?

[image]

Also, is there any good reference for this material? Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, the second and third figure are contained in the allowed example ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I may have mistakenly written "allowed" in the last picture due to misinterpretation. Any ideas about the first three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A 1-dimensional simplex is a line segment with two end points. The line segment in the first figure does not have two end points.
- In a simplicial complex, the intersection of two of the simplices is either empty or is a single face of both. In the second figure, the intersection between the two 1-dimensional simplices consists of the two points, whereas a single face would be a single point.
- The third figure suffers from the same problems.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Do you know any good reference for learning about simplicial complexes?

Comment: There are lots of references. Munkres's book "Elements of Algebraic Topology" is one of many standard references for simplicial complexes. nLab is usually reliable, although I haven't read their simplicial complex web page carefully: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+complex. They provide another few references, also.